# ES6 Object Destructuring Default Parameters

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to use object destructuring of default parameters without worrying about the object being partially defined. Consider the following:

```js
(function test({a, b} = {a: "foo", b: "bar"}) {
  console.log(a + " " + b);
})();
```

When I call this with `{a: "qux"}`, for instance, I see `qux undefined` in the console when what I really want is `qux bar`. Is there a way to achieve this without manually checking all the object's properties?

Answer (score 253, accepted):

Yes. You can use "defaults" in destructuring as well:

```js
(function test({a = "foo", b = "bar"} = {}) {
  console.log(a + " " + b);
})();
```

This is not restricted to function parameters, but works in every destructuring expression.

Comment: Nifty! It seems like setting the defaults on the destructuring side (the way you're doing it) would always be preferred to doing it on the default parameter side (like I was). Would you agree with that? Can you think of anything to watch out for?

Comment: I don't think one is "preferred" over the other. It just does something else.

Comment: This guards against `undefined`, but still errors if `b` is `null` right? Any way to protect against both `undefined` and `null` when destructuring? Ex: `{a: "qux", b: null}` would still error.

Comment: @AlanHamlett No, destructuring only deals with `undefined` - passing `null` must be done explicitly, and therefore leads to an error. To deal with both `null` and `undefined`, use the standard `b == null ? "bar" : b` inside the function.

Comment: @Bergi Could you explain what the difference between your answer and `test({a="foo", b="bar"})` is?

Comment: @YonggooNoh See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41108626/1048572) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34275971/1048572)

Comment: Basically, if you want to do just `new YourClass()`, use `= {}` if some parameters are mandatory, don't.

Comment: Typescript doesn't seem to recognize this well : (

Comment: @BT Yes it does. If you're having trouble to make it work (or add type annotations), please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and share the code that doesn't work

Comment: @Bergi I've figured out my typescript issue. The type must describe the acceptable *argument*, and not the resulting *parameter* type. IE in this case, the argument can accept undefined values for the defaulted parmaters, while the *parameters* themselves will never have undefined values for the defaulted parameters. Just a bit confusing.

Comment: plus some info, you can rename prop like this: ` (function test({a = "foo", b:c = "bar"} = {}) {
  console.log(a + " " + c);
})();`