# How to destructure option argument with all default values in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I use ES6 features with babel compiler.
I have a function which takes option object as an argument:

```
function myFunction({ option1 = true, option2 = 'whatever' }) {
    console.log(option1, option2);
    // do something...
}
```

When I call it, destructuring happens and everything works well.
I want to call it with default options most of the time, so I do:

```
myFunction({}); // true 'whatever'
```

but it looks little bit strange. It would much more cleaner just call:

```
myFunction(); // TypeError: Cannot read property 'option1' of undefined
```

Is it possible?

Comment: see also [ES6 destructuring object assignment function parameter default value](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38064644/1048572)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, you just have to provide a default value for the complete *argument*:

```
function myFunction({option1 = true, option2 = 'whatever'} = {}) {
//                                                         ^^^^
    console.log(option1, option2);
    // do something...
}
```