# How do I pass ES6 default parameters from a subclass to its superclass?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've got this code:

```
class Plant {
  constructor({name = 'General Plant', height = 0, depth = 1, age = 0}) {
    this.name = name;
    this.stats = {
      height: height,
      depth: depth,
      age: age
    };
  }
}

class Bush extends Plant {
  constructor({name = 'General Bush', height = 2, depth = 2}) {
    super(arguments)
  }
}
```

But calling `myBush = new Bush({})` results in an object with the name "General Plant" instead of "General Bush". Is there any way to set the default values in the subclass without having to manually call `this.name = name` in the constructor?

Comment: I know that when I'm calling `super(arguments)` that it's the raw arguments supplied to `new Bush`. I'm wanting to know if there's a way I can pass the arguments that have been modified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default initialisers don't mutate the [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) (such happened only in ye olde sloppy mode).
You need to pass the actual values from the parameter variables:

```
class Bush extends Plant {
  constructor({name = 'General Bush', height = 2, depth = 2, age}) {
    super({name, height, depth, age});
  }
}
```

Alternatively (but with different behaviour for `undefined` values and surplus properties) you might employ [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
class Bush extends Plant {
  constructor(opts) {
    super(Object.assign({name: 'General Bush', height: 2, depth: 2}, opts));
  }
}
```

Comment: So, if I'm too lazy to write the name of a variable more than once (which I am), then I'd have to give up on using the cool new ES6 default parameters and manually extend the arguments like this: `constructor(){ super($.extend(arguments, { name: 'General Bush', ... }) }`?

Comment: Variables are only introduced to use them more than once :-) Notice that `$.extend` (or better `Object.assign`) has slightly different semantics than default intialisers.

Comment: Yeah, I just now realized I should've used `Object.assign` in my example. Still used to old fashioned jQuery filling in the holes of ES5. I figured I'd have to give up on using default parameters for constructors since the way I have it setup still errors out when you call `new Bush()` without an object.

Comment: @Andrew For that, you need [a default `= {}` for the whole parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41108626/1048572)

Comment: Apparently not. this works perfectly: `constructor() { super(Object.assign({name: 'General Bush', height: 2, depth: 2}, ...arguments)) }`

Comment: I meant you need it when you don't want to give up on default parameters :-)