# How can I use default parameters when no value are passed in creating a new object?

Tags: javascript, class, parameter-passing, destructuring

I'm trying to pass parameters to a new class constructor and have default parameters calculated if no arguments are passed, whilst still having the option of passing any parameter by it's argument name.

```
class thing{
 constructor({a = 0, b = 0}) { 
  if(a == 0){this.a= func();}
  else {this.a = a;}
  if(b == 0){this.b= func();
  else {this.b = b;}
}
var defaultThing = new thing(); // returns Cannot destructure property `a` of 'undefined' or 'null'. 
var parametersThing = new thing({b:20}); // returns {a = 0, b = 20}
```

The problem is that when no parameters are passed the error `` Cannot destructure property `a` of 'undefined' or 'null'. `` is returned.

How can I use default parameters and still be able to use no parameters without encountering this error?

Comment: `({a = 0, b = 0} = {})`

Comment: wow, annoyed that i was duped by something so simple! Do you know where I can read up on why this works?

Comment: @Srick - In a couple of months, Chapters 3 and 7 of my new book would help. ;-) See my profile for details...

Comment: You could check out some answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38064644/2950032

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your constructor signature, you've supplied destructuring defaults for when the properties don't exist on the parameter received, but no default parameter. To do that, you add a default parameter:

```
//                         vvvv−−− default parameter value
constructor({a = 0, b = 0} = {}) {
//             ^^^−−−−^^^−−−−−−−−− destructuring defaults
    // ...
```

If you call that with no arguments, the default parameter value (`{}`) kicks in, and then the destructuring defaults kick in because that `{}` object doesn't have `a` or `b`.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense.

I had previously been calling the class as:
`var defaultThing = new thing({});`
Now I understand why that worked :)