# Function parameter value isn't working in object-destructuring in JS

Tags: javascript, object-destructuring

Let's assume that I've the following object:

```
let filters = {
  brands: { ... },
  price: { ... },
  sizes: { ... },

  ...
}
```

The properties of the `filters` object will be set by the users. Which means sometimes the `filters` object may contain just `brands`, sometimes it may contain `brands` & `price` and so on.

I've written the following function to extract a specific property from the `filters` object:

```
let extractProperty = (propertyName) => {
  ({ propertyName, ...rest } = filters);  // <-- propertyName isn't working here
  console.log(propertyName);
}

extractProperty("brands");
```

If I invoke the above function, the console displays `undefined`.
Can anyone please point me out what I'm missing here?

[CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/syed_n_sakib/pen/abNPYqZ?editors=0011)

**Note:**

I've already resolved this issue using [lodash.omit](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#omit) method. But I'm still curious to know why function parameter value isn't working in object-destructuring.

**Not Duplicate:**

1. [This question is about passing default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38064644/es6-destructuring-object-assignment-function-parameter-default-value)

Comment: it tries to destructure `propertyName` itself out of the object and not `brands`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code is looking for a property called `propertyName`, literally. To use the value in `propertyName` as the property name, you need to use computed notation, and you'll need to specify where to put the property's value. For instance, to put it in an existing `example` variable:

```
let extractProperty = (propertyName) => {
  ({ [propertyName]: example, ...rest } = filters);
//   ^−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^
  console.log(example);
};

extractProperty("brands");
```

Your code is written assuming that `rest` already exists, but I suspect you really want to declare it locally, along with the variable to receive the property value:

```
let extractProperty = (propertyName) => {
  const { [propertyName]: example, ...rest } = filters;
  console.log(example);
};

extractProperty("brands");
```

Without `const`, `let` (or `var`, but `var` is deprecated), unless you have `rest` declared in an enclosing scope, that code will either fail with a `ReferenceError` (in strict mode) or fall prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) (in loose mode), automatically creating a global variable.

Comment: (FWIW, I go into destructuring in a fair bit of detail in Chapter 7 of my new book, links in my profile if you're interested.)

Answer (score 0):

why use destructuring here when you just want to get a property?

```js
let filters = {
  brands: { value:'b' },
  price: { value:'p' },
  sizes: { value:'s' },
}

let extractProperty = propertyName =>
  console.log(filters[propertyName])

extractProperty("brands");
```