# Why is my destructuring failing?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have code similar to the following:

```
class Foo {
  foo() {
    return this.query( { key : "value" }, {
      multiple: true,
      resolveForeignKeys: false
    } );
  }

  query( conditions, {
    cast = null,
    multiple = false,
    resolveForeignKeys = true
  } = {} ) {
    console.log( "working..." );
  }
}

(new Foo()).foo();
```

This code works fine when I run it in the browser. However, when I run it through Node, I will get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'multiple' of undefined.
```

When I remove the default value `= {}` from the function declaration, the code will run fine. I'm also sure that this worked fine on another machine the other day.

I also found [How to destructure option argument with all default values in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34275971/how-to-destructure-option-argument-with-all-default-values-in-es6) where the answer suggests that the problem comes from a *missing* default value (`= {}`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a destructuring related bug that was [fixed in Node 6.9.2](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V6.md#6.9.2)

> #### Notable Changes
>
> - **deps**:
>
>   - *V8*: Various fixes to destructuring edge cases
>
>     - cherry-pick 3c39bac from V8 upstream (Cristian Cavalli) [#9138](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/9138)
>     - cherry pick 7166503 from upstream v8 (Cristian Cavalli) [#9173](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/9173)