# JS function declaration: curly brace object assigned with an empty object in parameter declaration

Tags: javascript

Here is the code,

```
export function createConnect({
    connectHOC = connectAdvanced,
    mapStateToPropsFactories = defaultMapStateToPropsFactories,
    mapDispatchToPropsFactories = defaultMapDispatchToPropsFactories,
    mergePropsFactories = defaultMergePropsFactories,
    selectorFactory = defaultSelectorFactory
} = {}) {...}
```

What does { connectHOC = connectAdvanced... } = {} mean inside the function parameter declaration?

I know that

```
= {}
```

could mean the default value of the function parameter, but what's the usage for the code inside previous braces?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure yet, but the first part (`{ connectHOC = ……… = defaultSelectorFactory }`) is not an object, it is a block with several variable declarations. An object would use colons, not equal signs.

Comment: It's a combination of default values for the parameters, and destructuring.  Surprised we don't appear to have a question covering both of those at the same time on SO yet, either that or my google is failing me this time.

Comment: [This is close](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26578167/es6-object-destructuring-default-parameters), but not quite a dupe.  [Also this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34275971/how-to-destructure-option-argument-with-all-default-values-in-es6).  They both explain what's going on here, but from the point of view of the OP knowing they want to assign default values to the destructured parameters, rather than a "what is this syntax" approach.

Comment: **TL;DR:** "...you can define a default value, so that your function doesn't have to take any arguments."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is ES2015 syntax. Your function declaration combines a [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) with a default value.

This is a basic destructuring assignment using an object:

```js
var {a, b} = {a: "foo", b: "bar"};
console.log(a); // "foo"
console.log(b); // "bar"
```

You can add default values to the left hand side:

```js
var {a = "foo", b = "bar"} = {};
console.log(a); // "foo"
console.log(b); // "bar"
```

When you name arguments when declaring a function, you don't use `var`, and with object destructuring it will be the same:

```js
function test({a = "foo", b = "bar"}){
    console.log(a + b);
}
test({}); // "foobar"
test({b: "boo"}); // "fooboo"
```

And, of course, you can define a default value, so that your function doesn't have to take any arguments.

```js
function test({a = "foo", b = "bar"} = {}){
    console.log(a + b);
}
test(); // "foobar"
```

Comment: Nice additional examples.

Comment: "...you can define a default value, so that your function doesn't have to take any arguments." Okay finally the actual answer...

Answer (score 3):

It's simply the way of doing default parameters using destructuring. You need the last bit as you suggested as a default.

Consider the following, which like the example uses a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
function withDefault({parameter=something} = {}) {
 console.log(parameter)
}

let something = 1;
withDefault();
```

versus this one, which is missing the default, and which throws an error:

```js
function withoutDefault({parameter=something}) {
 console.log(parameter)
}

let something = 1;
withoutDefault();
// It needs to be called as withoutDefault({}), withoutDefault(1) or
// with some value, since the function signature doesn't define a default
// in this case.
```