# ES6 Object Destructuring Default Values for Nested Parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parameters, ecmascript-6, react-redux

I'm using es6 object destructuring to provide default parameters to a function.

```
function mapStateToProps({ shops: { cakeShop: {}, pieShop: {} }) {
  return {
    CakeShopName: shops.cakeShop.Name,
    PieShopName: shops.pieShop.Name
  }
}
```

The problem with the above is that if I call

```
mapStateToProps({})
```

The code throws `Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined`. The nested objects on `shops` are not set to their default values and the code has a null reference.

How can I make sure that the nested objects within `shops` are being set to the right default value, even if `shops` itself is defined?

Comment: I don't think you can do that with destructuring, it works only if you are sure...

Comment: Sound like you were confusing destructuring with default values. Your syntax destructures an argument object, but doesn't actually introduce any parameter identifiers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sound like you were confusing destructuring with default values. Your syntax destructures an argument object, but doesn't actually introduce any parameter identifiers. There is no `shops` variable in your function scope.

I'll assume that you actually wanted to introduce `cakeShop` and `pieShop` variables, and provide them with defaults. To do that, you'd write

```
function mapStateToProps({ shops: { cakeShop = {}, pieShop = {} }) {
// short for             { shops: { cakeShop: cakeShop = {}, pieShop: pieShop = {} }) {
// parameter names (that will be bound):      ^^^^^^^^                ^^^^^^^
  return {
    CakeShopName: cakeShop.Name,
    PieShopName: pieShop.Name
  }
}
```

You might also use

```
function mapStateToProps({ shops: { cakeShop: {name: CakeShopName} = {}, pieShop: {name: PieShopName} = {} }) {
  return {CakeShopName, PieShopName};
}
```

Comment: This is right. As far as I can see, this is the same as @estus answer but with cleaner syntax (without the extra two `= {}` at the end?)

Comment: @glcheetham [Those defaults are needed](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34275971/1048572) when you want to be able to call the function with an object that has no `shops` property or without any argument at all.

Answer (score 7):

To handle default values for nested objects, it should be

```
function mapStateToProps({ shops: { cakeShop = {}, pieShop = {} } = {} } = {}) {
...
}
```

Comment: This works but now `shops` is undefined within the function scope. What if I need to access alot of props on `shops`?

Comment: The code in the question doesn't explain that. cakeShop, etc can be used as `cakeShop.Name`. If you really need `shops` then don't use param destructuring and do `const { cakeShop = {}, pieShop = {} } = shops` instead. You cannot have both shops and cakeShop from param destructuring at the same time.

Comment: you can: `{shops, shops: { cakeShop = {}, pieShop = {} } = {} } = {}` - keep in mind that if e.g. `cakeShop` is `null`, `false` or `0` your default will be set

Comment: @Dude Defaults are applied to `undefined` only. It's the opposite, if a value can be null then defaults won't be applied, if they are desirable then destructuring is unsuitable in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is about destructuring but for anyone interested I'm leaving another option here using `lodash` or `underscore`:

```
function mapStateToProps(shops) {
  _.defaultsDeep(shops, {
    cakeShop: {
      Name: "Kiki's CakeShop"
    }, 
    pieShop: {}
  })

  return {
    CakeShopName: shops.cakeShop.Name, // defaults to "Kiki's CakeShop"
    PieShopName: shops.pieShop.Name // undefined if not specified
  }
}
```