# Make the default apply for individual fields for an object argument

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, default-value

One of the arguments to my method should be an object.
Like usual, I can specify a default value for it in the prototype.

But this default is only used if I omit this argument in a call completely.

Yet I wish for it to apply on field level: if I provide a value but omit some fields that are present in the default, they should be filled in from it:

```
function method(id, data, options = { original: true, duplicate: true }) {
    console.log(options.original);
    console.log(options.duplicate);
}

method("id", "data", { duplicate: false })
// undefined <= I expect this to be true
// false

method("id", "data")
// true
// true
```

Any parameters not specified in the default should be accepted as well and passed as is:

```
method("id", "data", { duplicate: false, other: false })
```

If there any *syntactic* facility I can use for that? And, even if there isn't and I must use custom logic, can I somehow extract the default value from the prototype in it?

[ES6 Object Destructuring Default Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26578167/es6-object-destructuring-default-parameters) achieves something similar but it converts the "fields" into separate variables (while I wish for them to remain inside the object) and it doesn't allow fields that aren't specified in the prototype.

Comment: Define "I want it to be able to pass other options, not only what I defined". How should they behave?

Comment: In my method function above, I can add another attribute to the options i.e: `other: false`. But all answers doesn't address that.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev That's a quite substantial edit. Are you sure it follows the OPs intentions? It might have been better to ask a new question.

Comment: @Bergi _"Are you sure it follows the OPs intentions?"_ - yes, I am. This is fully in line with example code and the comment. The only questionable bit is the limit on requested means ("syntactic" or extract default) but that's necessary to avoid the "too broad" verdict: not just any solution but close to the way the OP sees his code.

Comment: And `func(({original = false, duplicate = true} = {original: true, duplicate: true})` won't work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can use default value assignment with the [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment/) notation:

```
function method(id, data, {original, duplicate} = { original: true, duplicate: true }) {
    console.log(original);
    console.log(duplicate);
}
```

Comment: That's exactly the behaviour that the OP wants to avoid

Comment: How'd you know that he wants to avoid it? Maybe he hasn't read the other answer.

Comment: "*If I call method with only one of defined options, the other options won't get its default value*". Your answer uses destructuring, but still has this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Default param values are on a variable-level only, not properties.
You're better off doing something like (pseudo-code):
`extend({ original: true, duplicate: true }, options)`

**Edit**:
It actually may be possible using destructuring, try this:
`function method(id, data, {original = true, duplicate = true} = {}) {}`

Comment: What do you mean "may" be possible? Didn't you try it before putting it in the answer?

Comment: No :( Didn't have time, am I a bad person?

Comment: You *may* be...