# es2015 dustruct inside function parameter

Tags: ecmascript-6

Can someone help inspect my code here? I don't know where the syntax error is.
My eslint (atom editor) says:

> *Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected : (Fatal)*

Here is the code:

```
const initialUserState = {}

const userReducer = (state = initialUserState, action: { type }) => {
  console.log(type)

  return state
}
```

I'm using babel-preset-env, which includes preset es2015, which then includes transform-es2015-destructuring.

And also, here is my babelrc config:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "browsers": ["last 2 versions", "safari >= 7"],
        "uglify": true
      },
      "modules": false
    }],
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    "react-hot-loader/babel"
  ]
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: That looks like typescript or something else with type annotations. It's invalid ES6 indeed. What did you expect it do, I cannot figure it out? What would the code look like without destructuring, or with destructuring in the function body?

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for

```
function userReducer(state = initialUserState, { action: type }) {
//                                             ^
```

which takes the `action` property of the second argument and introduces it as the variable `type` in the function scope. You just have misplaced the brace.

Comment: My guess:  `function userReducer(state = initialUserState, {type})` (`action` being the second argument passed in), or to actually be able to access `action`: `function userReducer(state = initialUserState, action) { const {type} = action; }`.

Comment: @FelixKling As good as mine… We really need a clarification of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Bergi and Felix for answering my question and the useful ideas.

---

After some googling and trying, I found this code working.

```
const userReducer2 = (
  state = initialUserState,
  { type: { name, sex } = { name: 'Peter', sex: 'male' } }
) => {
  console.log(name, sex) // eslint-disable-line no-console

  return state
}
```

What I'm trying to do is define variable names and give them default values at the same time.

Though I still don't know how to give the second parameter an `action` name, this shoul be sufficient.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26578323/1048572). And no, there's no way to make a parameter named and have it destructured at the same time. Just move the destructuring inside the function body for that.