# How to supplement the object with fields from default values?

Tags: typescript

I have function definition:

```
export function DivotTemplate(divot: Divot = {step: 8, triangleWidth: 4, radius: 0.6, strokeStyle: '#000'}, canvas: HTMLCanvasElement): HTMLCanvasElement {}
```

I want to be able pass not all object parameters like this:

```
DivotTemplate({step: 10});
```

As result to get this inside body of function:

```
{step: 10, triangleWidth: 4, radius: 0.6, strokeStyle: '#000'}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: What about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26578167/es6-object-destructuring-default-parameters

Comment: You could also do `DivotTemplate(divot) { divot = { step: 8, triangleWidth: 4, /*...*/, ...divot } /* function body */ }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call `updateDivot({step: 10});`, use [`Partial<Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype)

```ts
interface Divot {
  step: number;
  triangleWidth: number;
  radius: number;
  strokeStyle: string;
}

function updateDivot(fieldsToUpdate: Partial<Divot>) {
  const divot: Divot = {
    step: 8,
    triangleWidth: 4,
    radius: 0.6,
    strokeStyle: '#000'
  };
  const updatedDivot = { ...divot, ...fieldsToUpdate };
  // use the object for further operations
}
```