# How to use an object as a function parameter in JS?

Tags: javascript, object, default-parameters

I created a function that should return an object with user data. I want the function to accept an object as a parameter and I'd like this object to be defined inside the function with all the values pre-defined as default parameters in case they are not passed at a function call. The example code has only 2 values but I will need to pass over 15. How can I achieve such a solution?

```
const userCreator = (name, age) => {
  if (name === undefined) {
    name = 'John'
  }
  if (age === undefined) {
    age = 25
  }
  return {
    name:name,
    age:age
  }
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] showing your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Side note: You can apply those defaults directly in the parameter list: `const userCreator = (name = "John", age = 25) => { /*...*/ };`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ES6 Object Destructuring Default Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26578167/es6-object-destructuring-default-parameters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...and I'd like this object to be defined inside the function with all the values pre-defined as default parameters in case they are not passed at a function call.

I think you're saying:

- You want the function to accept an object
- You want all the properties of that object to be optional with defaults specified by the function

To do that, you can use [destructuring defaults](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#default_value). But see also below, because in this *specific* case, where you want to return an object, you may want to use a different approach.

But let's start with just basic destructuring without defaults, then add them:

```
const userCreator = ({ name, age }) => {
//                   ^−−−−−−−−−−−^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− destructuring
    // ...stuff with `name` and `age` here...
    return {
        name,
        age,
    };
};
```

To add defaults for those properties, you add them within the destructuring pattern (the `{}` where the parameter name would otherwise be):

```
const userCreator = ({ name = "John", age = 25, }) => {
//                         ^^^^^^^^^−−−−−^^^^^−−−− defaults for the properties
    return {
        name,
        age,
    };
};
```

If there are lots, probably best to break up into lines:

```
const userCreator = ({
    name = "John",
    age = 25,
}) => {
    return {
        name,
        age,
    };
};
```

That version still expects an object to be provided, though. If you want to allow `userCreator()` (no parameter passed at all), you need to add a default parameter value for the object parameter:

```
const userCreator = ({
    name = "John",
    age = 25,
} = {}) => {
//^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− default for the parameter
    return {
        name,
        age,
    };
};
```

That uses `{}` as the default value if no parameter is provided at all, `"John"` as the default if `name` isn't provided, and `25` as the default if `age` isn't provided. And since there is no `name` or `age` on the default `{}`, they get defaulted when you do `userCreator()`.

---

The alternative approach:

Since you want to return an object, you might just accept the object parameter directly, then use property spread or `Object.assign` to fill in defaults, like this:

```
const userDefaults = {
    name: "John",
    age: 25,
};
const userCreator = (template) => {
    const result = {        // The result object we'll return
        ...userDefaults,    // Fill in defaults
        ...template         // Overwrite with any properties from the caller
    };
    // Or with `Object.assign` in older environments without property spread:
    //const result = Object.assign(
    //    {},                 // The result object we'll return
    //    userDefaults,       // Fill in defaults
    //    template            // Overwrite with any properties from the caller
    //);
    return result;
};
```

Property spread and `Object.assign` both ignore `null` or `undefined`, so if no object is passed at all, `template` is `undefined`, and

Comment: Magic! Thank you so much! I believe the option with property spread is what I was looking for all along! Thanks again for all the detailed explanations :)

Answer (score -1):

You should define default values directly in the function parameters:

```js
const userCreator = (name = 'John', age = 25) => {
  return {
    name: name,
    age: age
  }
};
```

Comment: This is what I am trying to avoid. Name and age are just an example. I have over 15 values to set in this function :(

Comment: Ah, OK. That wasn't clear.